# Pasar valor de Dateinput a variable en Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

*... soy un poco novato en esto de django, se como hacer este tipo de consultas en javascript, yii, jquery pero en django se me hace un poco complicado.*

Creando una busqueda por rango de fechas, pues quiero llevar un control de ingresos por semanas, meses, trimestres y semestres,  en django me he topado con esto:

cuando hago la consulta  a la base de datos

```
ingresos.objects.filter(fecha__range=(f_inicial, f_cierre)
```

quiero que f_inicial y f_cierre tome el valor de fecha que yo elija en el Dateinput que defino en el Formulario, como puedo hacer esto, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debido a que lo que recibes desde tu formulario es un string, debes convertir este mismo es un objeto datetime que puedas utilizar como parametro para tus búsquedas

Suponiendo que lo que recibes desde tu front end, viene formateado en
dd/mm/aaaa

en tu view:

```
 import datetime

 def mi_vista(request):
     f_inicial = request.POST.get("f_inicial")
     f_inicial_a_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(f_inicial, '%d/%m/%Y')
     # lo anterior te genera un objeto datetime por ejemplo
     # datetime.datetime.strptime("31/03/2017", "%d/%m/%Y")
     # datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 0, 0)

     # hacemos lo mismo con fecha de cierre
     f_cierre = request.POST.get("f_cierre")
     f_cierre_a_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(f_cierre, '%d/%m/%Y')

     # y ahora si puedes aplicarlo a tus busquedas

     Ingresos.objects.filter(fecha__range=(f_inicial_a_datetime, f_cierre_a_datetime))

     # En vista de que el objeto date time te devolvera la fecha desde la hora 0
     # si deseas solo la fecha del objeto obtenido puedes hacerlo con f_inicial.date() o f_cierre.date()
```

Espero sea de ayuda!

Comment: todo bien, pero me da este error `type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'`

Comment: fíjate en tu importación, en el ejemplo estoy importando todo el modulo datetime `import datetime` por eso hago la utilización de `datetime.datetime` seguro estas importando el submodulo datetime `from datetime import datetime`, de ser ese el caso el uso sería por ejemplo `datetime.strptime(f_inicial, '%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: si era problema de mi importacion, solo que ahora devuelve un `must be string, not None` en `    desde_a_datetime = datetime.strptime(desde, '%d/%m/%Y')

`

Comment: asegurate que estes obteniendo correctamente la variable que viene en el post, al ejecutar `request.POST.get("nombre_variable")` te devolvera un `None` si el nombre que intentas obtener no viene como una variable POST

Comment: Vale, he revisado todo eso y vi un pequeño error que solucione... he aqui mi codigo en virew.py

Comment: Me alegra, logré ver el post que colocaste por error como respuesta, el error que te da con la variable `filtro` es que la estas utilizando en el método render, pero la misma no ha sido inicializada ya que la creas dentro de tu bloque `if form.is_valid()` cuando no sea valido el form no se creará y te arrojará ese error, en su lugar te recomiendo uses `locals()`

Comment: puedes también puntuar los comentarios que han sido de ayuda @RolyMirandaDíaz, y si tienes otra pregunta, puedes perfectamente abrirla ya que escapa del alcance de esta

Comment: vale nueva pregunta http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62054/mostrar-datos-de-filtro-de-fechas-django muchas gracias, y te doy los puntos.