# Mostrar datos de filtro de fechas en Django

Tags: python, django

Lo que deseo es hacer un filtro de datos y mostrar valores según fechas.

Para hacer evaluaciones, mensuales, trimestrales etcétera.

Para explicarme mejor, les dejo mis view.py y mi form.py

form.py

```
class FiltroFechas(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ingresos
        fields = ['desde', 'hasta', 'jovenclub']
        widgets = {
             'desde': forms.DateInput(format=('%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y',), attrs={'class': 'form-control bs-datepicker', 'placeholder': 'Seleccione la fecha Correcta'}),
             'hasta': forms.DateInput(format=('%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y',), attrs={'class': 'form-control bs-datepicker', 'placeholder': 'Seleccione la fecha Correcta'})
        }
```

View.py

```
 def inicio(request):
    plan_gral = jovenclub.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('plan_gral'))
    juridic_gral = ingresos.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('juridico'))
    natural_gral = ingresos.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('natural'))
    general = juridic_gral['sum']+natural_gral['sum']
    porciento_general = general*100/plan_gral['sum']
    ingreso = ingresos.objects.all()
    form = FiltroFechas(request.POST)


    if form.is_valid():
        desde = request.POST.get("desde")
        desde_a_datetime = datetime.strptime(desde, '%d/%m/%Y')
        # hasta = request.POST.get('hasta')
        hasta = request.POST.get("hasta")
        hasta_a_datetime = datetime.strptime(hasta, '%d/%m/%Y')
        filtro=ingresos.objects.filter(fecha__range=(desde_a_datetime, hasta_a_datetime))

        print filtro
        return render_to_response('index.html', {'form':form, 'resultado':filtro})

    return render_to_response('index.html', {'porciento':porciento_general, 'form':form, 'general':general, 'plan_gral':plan_gral,'suma':plan_gral['sum'], 'juridico':juridic_gral['sum'], 'ingreso':ingreso, 'natural':natural_gral['sum']}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: gracias x la edicion parece que tuve error al publicarla...

Comment: ya intentaste usar `{{ datos.fecha.value }}`?

Comment: ¿`form` es un formulario o es un _queryset_? ¿Puedes hacer `form.as_p`? Si `Filtrofechas` es una instancia de `forms.ModelForm` o similares, pues entonces `datos` debería dibujar un control o un _widget_... pero tu esperas otra cosa. Creo que falta información a tu pregunta.

Comment: @RolyMirandaDíazpor favor edita tu pregunta y añade este segmento a ella, es mas facil leerlo que en un comentario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes renderizar es el contenido de tu variable `resultado` que es como la declaras al momento de utilizar `render_to_response` y ademas es la que contiene los valores que filtras en tu view mediante la variable `filtro`, ya que `form` es una instancia de tu formulario y no contiene los valores que extraes segun tu rango, por ende debes tener algo como lo siguiente en tu template:

```
{% for datos in resultado %}
    {{datos.fecha}}
{% endfor %}
```

Del mismo modo te recomiendo que previo al `form.is_valid()` puedas quizás inicializar tu variable filtro:

`filtro = None`

De manera que tengas un solo return en tu view, puedes utilizar `locals()` en lugar de estar creando un dict con cada una de las variables que desees retornar

`return render_to_response('index.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

Espero sea de ayuda

Comment: ... nada no veo resultado alguno, y hay valores en la base de datos pues el resto del sistema funciona bien, solo necesito hacer ese tipo de consulta de datos por rango de fechas, gracias a usted

Comment: @RolyMirandaDíaz Asegurate que el flujo del view esta entrando por `form.is_valid()` debido a que cuando el form no sea valido `resultado` estará vacio y no se renderizará nada en tu template

Comment: Igual bro he probado de diferentes formas y no logro pintar el resultado de e el filtro

Comment: @RolyMirandaDíaz por favor añade entonces añade a tu pregunta el codigo de tu template y descrie exactamente el flujo que esta llevando. Esoy mas que seguro que los datos que intentas imprimir no se están cargando en el view. Pudiera probar inicializando la variable que quieres renderizar con un valor aleatorio (y comentar la iteracion) y mostrarla en el template, si te muestra ese valor que colocaste por defecto, es por que en efecto no se esta almacenando el valor que deseas iterar

Comment: si acabo de probarlo con valores de fechas fijos y si funciona el rango, los datos no se estan cargando en la view, como dices

Comment: hecho, cambie la logica del proyecto, no me era necesario ese tipo de filtro, pero me distes la solucion exacta para lo que necesitaba, gracias!! @Angel F